# How to focus on a element the right way?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

Im doing webtest using selenium Webdriver in C#. But I'm having a problem where when the browser window isn't in full size a popup will open half way outside the visible area.

The problem is that when i fire a .Click(); it doesn't do anything because the link i attempt to click is outside of the viewed area.

So how do i focus on the link to get click to work? Im currently using the following workaround but i don't think that's a nice way.

```
        _blogPostPage.FindElement(By.XPath(_popupLogin)).SendKeys("");
        _blogPostPage.FindElement(By.XPath(_popupLogin)).Click();
```

The sendkeys with space focuses on the link and makes Click work everytime, but isn't there a right way to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We've been playing with Selenium and have run into this problem as well. I don't know if it's the WebDriver as a whole, the C# implementation, the version of Firefox etc, but we have found an ok workaround:

The trick is to force Selenium to evaluate the `LocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView` property on the `RemoteWebElement` class (which is inherited by `FirefoxWebElement` and implements `IWebElement`). This forces the browser to scroll so that the element is in view.

The way we've done it is to use an extension method:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;

namespace Namespace
{
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static IWebElement FindElementOnPage(this IWebDriver webDriver, By by)
        {
            RemoteWebElement element = (RemoteWebElement)webDriver.FindElement(by);
            var hack = element.LocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView;
            return element;
        }
    }
}
```

this way all we have to do is change the generated code from:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("elementId")).Click();
```

to:

```
driver.FindElementOnPage(By.Id("elementId")).Click();
```

Hope it works for you!?

Comment: Cool thanks, I'll try on monday :),, Looks better than my solution ;)

Comment: I also used this code before. But with the newer Gecko drivers LocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView only returns coordinates but does NOT scroll anymore! This solution is outdated now. Thank you Gecko folks! You broke it!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing send key for blank value, send it for space. Thats the keyboard shortcut to select a checkbox.

Just replace the code :

```
_blogPostPage.FindElement(By.XPath(_popupLogin)).SendKeys("");
_blogPostPage.FindElement(By.XPath(_popupLogin)).Click();
```

by

```
_blogPostPage.FindElement(By.XPath(_popupLogin)).SendKeys(Keys.Space);
```

Answer (score 0):

`driver.find_element(:id, "edit-section").send_keys " "` with the space worked for me.

I am using webdriver rspec with selenium-server-2.24.1 and I was having trouble with IE8 - I kept getting `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError`.  It was working in IE9 and FF but not IE8 until I added send_keys " ".